# Alphabetize individual strings from list - Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, char

I want to read in a list of words.  Then I want alphabetize each of the characters within each word such that I have an entire list of words where each letter is alphabetized. For example if I wanted to read in "cat" "dog" "mouse" from a text file I would have [a,c,t], [d,g,o], and [e,m,o,s,u].

I'm implementing this in Java. I thought about a linked list or some other Collection but I'm not really sure how to implement those with respect to this. I know it's not as simple as converting each string to a char array or using array list. (I already tried those)

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples of doing this?

Basically, I'm just trying to get better with algorithms.

```
 public class AnagramSolver1 {

static List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/dictionary.txt"));
    String line = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (null!=(line=in.readLine()))
    {
       dictionary.add(line);
    }
    in.close();

    char[] word;


    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); i++) {
        word = inputList.get(i).toCharArray();
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Comment: How do you plan to use the collection? Search for the letters of a specific word? Just output the whole list? In reding order? alphabetic order of the original word? etc. The optimal solution depends on many factors.

Comment: Why not include some code that you tried.  You indicated that you tried breaking the words into char arrays and it didn't work.  It is in fact possible to do it that way.  Show us how you tried it.

Comment: @greedybuddha Yes, I'd like to sort the letters. I kind of figured it would be a list of arrays - or something like that - that I would eventually compare to yet another list.

Comment: @EricWich I've included some code. It's really simple right now. It's the beginnings of an anagram solver. There are a lot of good posts out there on anagrams. One mentioned this method. Thought I'd try it out.

Comment: You should realise that "A" and "a" have different  lexical values. Do you want to preserve uppercase? And what if there are repeated letters in a word? If you are anagramming you probably want to lowercase everything and retain repeated letters

Comment: Ok, so I should convert everything to lower case then. Sounds good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `String` called `word`, you can obtain a sorted `char[]` of the characters in `word` via [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D%29)

```
char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
```

I assume you would want to repeat this process for each member of a collection of words.

If you're interested in knowing what happens behind the scenes here, I would urge you to take a look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort1%28char%5B%5D,int,int%29).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Basically I'm reading words from a dictionary file and I want to alphabetize the letters of each word. I'm trying to make an anagram solver. I read another really good post which recommended this process. Thought I'd give it a try. My previous method was use all permutations -which seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides good support for sorting already: all you need is converting your `String` to an array of `char[]`, call `Arrays.sort` on it, and then convert that array back to `String`.

If you want to have some fun with algorithms, however, you could try going for a linear [*counting sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort): count the letters in the original, then go through the counts in alphabetical order, and write out the `count` number of characters.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I'll look into this. Thanks.